# ¿Por qué no puedo compilar ningún código en CodeBlocks?

Tags: linux, codeblocks

Acabo de instalar *CodeBLocks (16.01)* en *Kubuntu* en su versión *18.04 LTS*. Cuando intento compilar y ejecutar cualquier código (incluido el `"Hello World!"` no abre la consola y solo me manda el mensaje:

> error:obj/Debug/main.o: No existe el archivo o el directorio

Ya tengo instalado el compilador *GNU GCC* y está configurado como compilador predeterminado, así que no se qué hacer.

Answer (score 0):

Esto seguramente no te valga como respuesta, ya que no he usado Codeblocks en la vida, pero por lo que veo estás intentando compilar C o C++.

El proceso de compilado de los lenguajes (valga la redundancia) compilados, pasa por un paso intermedio que es crear los .o, que son *object files*, es decir, archivos en binario que luego el compilador enlaza entre ellos para crear el ejecutable de tu programa.

En este caso el error te dice que no encuentra main.o, es decir, que cuando intenta generar el ejecutable de tu main.c, no encuentra su .o correspondiente. Se me ocurre que puede ser por:

1. Le estás dando a ejecutar o generar ejecutable directamente, y hay algún botón de compilado por ahí que deberías darle antes.
2. La ruta donde se genera el .o es distinta de donde se genera el ejecutable, y si intenta mirar en la misma carpeta, pues no lo encuentra.

Si son programas muy sencillos (y estás usando Unix), es más sencillo compilar por consola de comandos que con un IDE:

`gcc main.c -o main`

Debería compilarte tu programa (a no ser que utilices librerías externas)

Comment: Codeblocks tiene una opción de compilar y ejecutar así que no es eso. Posiblemente sea lo segundo que mencionaste. Lo revisaré y te aviso. Gracias!

Comment: ¿Qué debo hacer si quiero incluir una librería externa?

Comment: Depende de si estás haciendo un include de un .h o de una librería, he encontrado este link que tiene ambos casos: https://www.rapidtables.com/code/linux/gcc/gcc-l.html

Comment: Por cierto, que no lo he comentado, temas como stdio, e includes que "te sacas de la manga", es decir, no te has bajado nada para usarlo, son propios del lenguaje y por tanto no hace falta que no indiques nada a la hora de compilar